# Checking the last child of my jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am making a jQuery slider, basically I show what slider is shown by adding the class currentmemory to each of the children of my memory2container.

Problem is when I reach the last slider instead of going back to the first slider and starting over it stops working.

You can check the simple code I am using for this here:

```js
$('.amsheart').click(function() {
 var cm = $('.memories2container').children('.currentmemory:first');
 var nm = cm.nextAll('.memory:first');
 if(cm.is('.memories2container:last-child')){
   nm = $('.memories2container').children('.currentmemory:first'); 
   cm.removeClass('currentmemory');
   nm.addClass('currentmemory');
 }
 else{
   cm.removeClass('currentmemory');
   nm.addClass('currentmemory');
 }
 
});
```

```css
.amsheart{position:relative; transform: rotate(-5deg);}

.amsterdam{position:absolute; left:851px; top:37px;}


.memory{display:none;}

.currentmemory{display:block;}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .1} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .1} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

.fadeout{opacity:1.0; transition: opacity 2s;}
.fadeout:hover{opacity:0.0; transition:opacity 2s; }
```

```html
<div class="memories2container" style="width:550px; height:600px; position:absolute; right:50px; top:100px; transform:rotate(1deg);">
    <div class="memory currentmemory fade" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; ">
   <div class="first fadeout" style="background-image: url('images/20170520_115819.jpg');"><div class="pin1"></div><div class="pin2"></div><div class="pin3"></div><div class="pin4"></div></div>
   <div class="second" style="background-image: url('images/20170520_115845.jpg');"><div class="pin1"></div><div class="pin2"></div><div class="pin3"></div><div class="pin4"></div></div>
   <p style="transform:rotate(1deg); position:absolute; top:315px; left:40px; width:500px; height:auto; margin:auto; margin-top:15px; font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive; font-weight:600; font-size:23px;">37, esta fue nuestra acojedora "casita" durante 3 dias en Amsterdam,  aunque parece pequeñita dentro habia espacio de sobra!</p>
   <p style="position:absolute; top:415px; left:150px; transform:rotate(1deg); font-size:22px; font-weight:600;">y nuestros vecinos eran adorables XD</p>
 </div>
 <div class="memory fade" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; ">
   <div class="first fadeout" style="background-image: url('images/20170522_124602.jpg');"><div class="pin1"></div><div class="pin2"></div><div class="pin3"></div><div class="pin4"></div></div>
   <div class="second" style="background-image: url('images/20170522_112958.jpg');"><div class="pin1"></div><div class="pin2"></div><div class="pin3"></div><div class="pin4"></div></div>
   <p style="transform:rotate(0.5deg); position:absolute; top:305px; left:38px; width:500px; height:auto; margin:auto; margin-top:15px; font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive; font-weight:600; font-size:23px;">Nuestro último dia en Lucky Lake, un lugar encantador! Mientras tu dabas los ultimos toques a tu perfecto ensayo en español yo me relajaba en la hamaca...</p>
   <p style="position:absolute; top:435px; left:154px; transform:rotate(-2deg); font-size:22px; font-weight:600;">todos deberian tener derecho a una hamaca!</p>
 </div>
 <div class="memory fade" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; ">
   <div class="first" style="background-image: url('images/20170521_030407.jpg');"><div class="pin1"></div><div class="pin2"></div><div class="pin3"></div><div class="pin4"></div></div>
   <p style="transform:rotate(0.5deg); position:absolute; top:315px; left:26px; width:500px; height:auto; margin:auto; margin-top:15px; font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive; font-weight:600; font-size:23px;">Calentando nuestra cena en la calidez de nuestra caravana tras un largo dia visitando la hermosa ciudad...</p>
   <p style="position:absolute; top:422px; left:140px; transform:rotate(1deg); font-size:22px; font-weight:600;">no es un Subway pero it's okeeyy !</p>
 </div>
 <div class="memory fade" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; ">
   <div class="first fadeout" style="background-image: url('images/20170520_121454.jpg');"><div class="pin1"></div><div class="pin2"></div><div class="pin3"></div><div class="pin4"></div></div>
   <div class="second" style="background-image: url('images/patitos.gif');"><div class="pin1"></div><div class="pin2"></div><div class="pin3"></div><div class="pin4"></div></div>
   <p style="transform:rotate(0.5deg); position:absolute; top:315px; left:26px; width:500px; height:auto; margin:auto; margin-top:15px; font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive; font-weight:600; font-size:23px;">Nuestros vecinos nos acompañan en el desayuno?! son una familia entera de patitos muy monos</p>
   <p style="position:absolute; top:422px; left:140px; transform:rotate(1deg); font-size:22px; font-weight:600;">ellos son otro tipo de churris con plumas !</p>
 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="amsterdam">
    <span>I</span>
    <img class="amsheart" src="images/heart3.png">
    <span>AMSTERDAM</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: You have not loaded your jquery library but trying to use jquery. First load a jquery library in your project then it will work fine.

Comment: I have the jquery library added in my file, that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Incrementing Index

> *"Problem is when I reach the last slider instead of going back to the first slider and starting over it stops working."*

The reason why you can't continue moving from last position to the first position is because you need to keep track incrementally. Using `.nextAll` and referencing the `first-child` and `last-child` without a true sense of exactly what is between first and last will get you stuck because those references are from the whole NodeList or array's perspective. You need the point of reference coming from the index-position of the active element. Without that, you don't have a stopping point and without a stopping point, methods like `.nextAll()` and `children` will continue and eventually not find anything and then fail.

Determine what part of your app actually "drives" the whole process forward and increment your count. All you need is to declare a variable with the value of 0, then increment it on every iteration (loop) or in your case click of the button.

```
   var idx = 0;

   $('button').on('click', function() {
      
      idx++;
      
      ...the rest of the code...

    });
```

Next, determine the limit of your cycle by identifying the total amount of the elements that are being counted and/or traversed. 99% of the time it's a collection, specifically an array, NodeList, HTMLCollection, or an object literal (even a string). More than likely, this is easily done with the `.length` property. By enforcing a limit, you'll establish when and where of the end and beginning of your cycles. Do that by comparing current count and total number of elements involved (-1 from that total to offset the 0 count)

```
   var idx = 0;

   $('button').on('click', function() {
      
      idx++;

      if (idx > (array.length -1)) {
        
         idx = 0;
   
       }

       ...the rest of the code...

    });
```

---

**References are located below demo**

**Details are commented in demo**

### Demo

```js
// Same as $(document).ready(function() {...
$(function() {

  // Reference main#frame as jQObj
  var frm = $('#frame');
  
  // Declare the base url to the images location
  var base = "https://i.imgur.com/";
  
  /* Declare an array of strings; Each string is an
  || image fileName and extension
  */
  var path = ['6qGdA1e.jpg', 'iBug1U8.jpg', 'EK7A1RX.jpg', 'exivDl4.jpg', 'qQxmYLj.jpg', 'zHvmZz3.jpg', 'rmx1Y0y.jpg', 'XAYwLxo.jpg', 'TQviM2Y.jpg', 'KrKOLmh.jpg'];
  
  //Get a count/Set a count
  var qty = path.length;
  var cnt = 0;

  // Run the array thru `map()` 
  path.map(function(img, idx, path) {
  
    /* This string is written as a Template Literal
    || ${var} is an interpolated variable
    || Refer to posted reference for details
    */
    var img = `<div class='image'><img src='${base}${path[idx]}' style='object-fit:contain' width='100%' height='100%'></div>`;
    
    /* After that, insert img into main#frame
    || Unlike innerHTML, insertAdjacentHTML()
    || does not overwrite old content.
    */
    frm[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', img);
    return img;
  });
  
  // Set the first image with the .active class
  $('.image').first().addClass('active');

  function movePaths(e) {
  
    // Increment cnt
    cnt++;
    
    // if cnt is more than 6...
    if (cnt > qty - 1) {
    
      // Reset cnt;
      cnt = 0;
    }
    
    // Get all div.image and remove .active class
    $('.image').removeClass('active');
    
    /* Get the div.image at the position 
    || within the $('.image') object that matches
    || the number cnt currently in and add
    || .active class to it
    */
    $('.image').eq(cnt).addClass('active');
  }
  
  /* Delegate the click event to button.heart 
  || callback is movePaths()
  */
  $('.heart').on('click', movePaths);

});
```

```css
/* Set H/W 100/100% so that the rest of your
|| layout has a reference when using relative 
|| measurements like `%` 
*/
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font: 400 16px/1.5 "Palatino Linotype"
}
/* In general, a parent element should have 
|| position:relative
|| The children elements should have 
|| position:absolute
*/ 
#frame {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 96%;
  height: 75vh;
}

/* Using display:table allows the container size to
|| conform to its contents
*/
.image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: table;
}

/* A .class repeat selector is a valid and safe
|| way to boost specificity. For details see references.
*/
.active.active {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 75vh;
  max-height: 600px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 222;
  animation: IN;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

.heart {
  border: 0 none transparent;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  outline: 0 none transparent;
  cursor: pointer
}

.heart::after {
  content: '';
  font-size: 32px
}

@keyframes IN {
  0 {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    transform: translateX(0)
  },
  33% {
    opacity: .33;
    height: 33%;
    transform: translateX(9vh)
  },
  66% {
    opacity: .66;
    height: 66%;
    transform: translateX(18vh)
  },
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateX(27vh)
  }
}
```

```html
-
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title></title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head><!-- This end tag is always before...
...the beginning of the body tag-->
<body>
  <main id='frame'>
  </main>
  <nav class="control">
    <label for='heart'>I</label>
    <button class="heart" type='button'></button>
    <label for='heart'>HAMSTER &#128057; HAM &#128055;</label>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body><!--body end tags are the second to the last
Remember a document can only have one <head> tag and one <body> tag.-->

</html>
```

### References

- [**Template Literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- **[insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)**
- [**map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [**CSS Specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: My pleasure, happy coding.